# Submitted app on iOS App Store: webscket connection fails

Tags: ios, xcode, websocket, app-store, app-store-connect

I have problems with establishing connection via websockets in my app that I submit to iOS App Store. I am using webosckets over SSL (secure version, wss://).

I have two ways of distributing it:

1. *Ad-hoc distribution.* Connection over websockets is there and everything works as intended. I get this distribution installed on my iPhone in the following way. From Xcode:

   1. Open **Archives** window.
   2. Select the latest archive and click **Export...**.
   3. Choose **Save for Ad Hoc deployment** and proceed several steps.
   4. Uncheck **Rebuild from bitcode**. Otherwise, the exporting is stuck on **Preparing Archive (Compile bitcode...)** step indefinitely. *I did not actually measure the indefinite amount of time.*
   5. Move generated .ipa file to iTunes and install it on the phone via iTunes.
   6. Rejoice for the app is blessed with Internet presence.
2. *App Store distribution.* Websocket connection fails and is never established. This is the version that I want to test by uploading to App Store and using TestFlight to test it.

   1. Open **Archives** window.
   2. Select the same archive as in the step above.
   3. Click **Upload to App Store...**
   4. Go to itunesconnect.apple.com and configure the build to be used for internal testing.
   5. Use TestFlight app on the phone to install my app.
   6. Realize that no Internet calls get through.
   7. Cry desperately.

The only apparent difference is that I turned **Rebuild from bitcode** option off. I have to do it because I cannot generate .ipa file otherwise.

Calls over HTTPS work in both versions.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get websocket connection on my builds that I upload to App Store?

Please ask for any details you might need which I did not provide.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally managed to solve the problem.

The culprit was in **Enable Bitcode** setting, it has to be turned off. I was, perhaps ignorantly, not aware of this option.

In Xcode, set **Build Settings -> Build Options -> Enable Bitcode** to **No**.

It is worth noting that this is a project generated from Unity engine, so it could be that bitcode conversion was affecting websocket libraries used in my Unity project.